# What are the US tax filing requirements for a non resident alien with a K1?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, schedule-k-1

For 2023 I am a non resident alien, actually a resident of the UK. I held USO or United Staes Oil fund in my brokerage account between February 2022 and March 2023 not knowing that is not an ETF but a publicly traded partnership.

After realizing what it was while filing 2022 taxes; I discarded it. In 2022 I had a W2 so I definitely had to file taxes but have no such obligations in 2023.

I am trying to figure out if I need to file taxes by the virtue of being involved in a PTP. I also have some K1s because I have made some tiny angel investments on AngelList but none of those have any income.

Update - confirming that this query is for the United States; I am a non-resident alien based as I have spent less than 2 weeks in the United States in 2023

Comment: Just to be very clear, are you asking whether you have to file *US* taxes? You haven't actually specified but i assume that's what you mean by the references to W2 etc.

Comment: "For 2023 I am a non resident alien" How did you determine that? Were you present in the US for less than 31 days in 2023? Or was (the number of days you were present in the US in 2023 + 1/3 the number of days you were present in the US in 2022 + 1/6 the number of days you were present in the US in 2021) less than 183 days?

Comment: Have you provided a W8 to the partnership/broker? Do they know you're a non-resident?

Comment: Yes! I mean US Taxes. I will clarify in the question!

I was present in the United States in 2023 for about 14 days! I am okay when it comes to the substantial presence test

I have told them last year that I am a non resident and they have me as a "Foreign Partner". I don't remember singing a W8-BEN for them.

Comment: If they have you as foreign partner, they should have given you a withholding certificate - did you get any?

Comment: I haven't got it yet. I think whatever documentaiton they have is due on the 1st of March

Comment: I have only received a K1 that marks me as a foreign entity